# How do I repair all corrupt lines ending from files on a subversion repository

Tags: svn, line-endings

I have a big subversion repository and I discovered that many .py files (and maybe others) do not have the proper line endings, generating problems when checked out on different platforms.

How can I solve this without repairing them one by one?

Also how to I prevent others from corrupting the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a SVN property "eol-style" for these files to "native". [Check this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html)

```
 svn propset svn:eol-style 'native'
```

Comment: The link ("Check this") appears to be broken.

Comment: @JonSchneider Thank you for noticing, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [svn-apply-autoprops](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvn.red-bean.com%2Fwsanchez%2Ftrunk%2Fsvn-support%2Fsvn-apply-autoprops&ei=6SwuTMrQBsuMOLL_5KMC&usg=AFQjCNHDhGLodPe3E02AygBVC2_yxs-yaw&sig2=7XuiVjwEXwcvbGzfnAY7WQ) script that comes as part of the source distribution -- it'll compare the properties of all checked out files with that in your subversion configuration file and then apply the correct properties.  As Pmod mentions, it's the svn:eol-style property that has to be set to `native`